# D3D9 multithread creating textures/vertex buffers

Tags: c++, multithreading, textures, directx-9, vertex-buffer

I'd like to have in my game second thread which would load/unload textures. Can I load textures in 2nd thread using the same d3d9 device which was created on main thread? Creating textures from file will take more time than 1 frame so I may need to create texture while the other thread is rendering scene. I'm not going to use texture that is being loaded of course. The same question about vertex buffers. Can I create them and fill with data while the other thread is rendering something?

Comment: Do you have any code that you've written so far?  Show us some work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED` flag when creating the device in order to be able to create D3D resources from a second thread. This is going to incur a very small runtime overhead on all DX API calls because it acquires a lock.

You can also, however, use the second thread to stream in raw data from disk and have the main thread create the D3D resource from it. This burdens you with the synchronization logic, at likely the same cost.

Multi-threaded D3D API use has become increasingly common and in fact, the above flag is the default with D3D11 (i.e. you have to tell it to be not thread-safe as opposed to requesting thread-safety).

Comment: I'm using D3D9, not D3D11. I don't need d3d11 for 2D game and d3d9 allows XP's users to play my game.
Back to thread - so with D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED flag any device method will lock device and any other threads will wait until that method ends?
I tried to load data from HDD to memory and then call D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemory but it seems that loading file to memory is 100 times faster than creating texture by DX so doing that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Direct3D 9 and Direct3D 10's multi-threaded handling are rather primitive. By default, Direct3D 9 is not thread safe. If you use ``D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED`` it takes a global lock on basically every API call so it's almost always too slow. Direct3D 10 is basically the reverse. Direct3D 11.x is the first version of the API that really tries to provide more granular threading control. That said, some people have had luck with doing a thread Lock on the 'rendering' thread and then pass the locked pointer to another thread to do loading and deal with all the sync yourself.

Comment: That said, using Direct3D 11 is a lot simpler. 2D games on Direct3D 11 is no stranger than Direct3D 9, and you might find that SpriteBatch in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) is most of what you actually need for a 2D game--Direct2D is a bit too cumbersome if you want to do fancy custom shaders. These days it's not really worth all the [pain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/10/22/goodbye-to-an-old-friend.aspx) of supporting Windows XP unless you are maintaining ancient code, or trying to ship a game in Russia or China.

Comment: So if I migrate from D9 to D11 I could easly manage resources like textures, vertex buffers in the other thread? Is it hard to learn Dx11? Is it much different than Dx9 when talking about 2D game (no shaders, lights etc.)?